# AngularJS 1.5 - Form submitted with empty required fields on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, forms, cordova

I am actually developing a Cordova application with AngularJS (1.5.11). I am facing a really strange bug with iOS which I don't have with Android (same code).

I removed all unneeded information from the form to reproduce the bug (classes, directives, extra divs...) and the bug is still there :(

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="$ctrl.login()">
    <input type="email" name="username" value="" required ng-model="$ctrl.username">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" required ng-model="$ctrl.password">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My form is submitting even if it is invalid. It is a basic login form with two fields (login, password) and a button.

Just for information, every form in my app is affected by this bug.

Did I miss something?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's an iOS bug. Report it to Apple https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options

1.- Disable the submit button if the form is invalid:

```
<form name="needNameForm" method="post" ng-submit="$ctrl.login()">
...
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="needNameForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

2.- Ignore the submit if the form is invalid:

```
<form name="needNameForm" method="post" 
ng-submit="needNameForm.$valid && $ctrl.login()">
...
</form>
```

3.- Check validity in your submit method:

```
<form name="needNameForm" method="post" 
ng-submit="$ctrl.login(needNameForm)">
...
</form>
<!-- for testing purposes you can use this line below -->
<pre>{{needNameForm | json}}</pre>
```

In your controller:

```
angular.controller('name', function(){
var vm = this;
vm.login = function(formController){
  if(formController.$valid){
   doStuff();
  }
 }
}
```

with this 3rd option you will have more control if you want to validate each input in your form, the **formController** object will have all info for each input, and also you will require to add a name to the inputs so you can get full info about them, here is all the info about it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I chose the third option but it's really annoying to have to develop form validation while it exists in the browser...